# Extending abstract classes and using same methods with different arguments

Tags: java, abstract-class

First of all, here's my abstract class:

```
public abstract class GeometricObject2D implements Comparable {
  public abstract boolean contains(GeometricObject2D g);
  public abstract boolean contains(double x, double y);
  public abstract boolean overlaps(GeometricObject2D g);
  public abstract int compareTo(Object temp);
  public abstract double getArea();
  public abstract double getPerimeter();

}
```

I'm supposed to extend it with two other classes, ComparableCircle2D and ComparableRectangle2D. Both contain all of the methods, except that they use their own arguments in the *contains* and *overlaps* methods, e.g:

```
public class ComparableCircle2D extends GeometricObject2D {
//...
  public boolean contains(ComparableCircle2D circle){
  //method
  }
//...
  public boolean overlaps(ComparableCircle2D circle){
  //method
  }
//...
}
```

This is the error I get:

**Error:(1, 8) java: ComparableCircle2D is not abstract and does not override abstract method overlaps(GeometricObject2D) in GeometricObject2D.**

Same goes for the other class. I don't fully understand what's wrong, so an explanation and a solution would be greatly appreciated.

P.S: The arguments *have to* stay the same.

Comment: You should use generics instead of raw types when you implement `Comparable`, i.e `implements Comparable<Geometric2DObject>` and `compareTo(Geometric2DObject other)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't do it.**

In your class you have to override all methods of the abstract class, then you have to override the method:

```
 @Override
 public boolean contains(GeometricObject2D g){...}
```

Hovewer you can use somenthing like this:

```
public abstract class GeometricObject2D<T extends GeometricObject2D> {
     public abstract boolean contains(T g);
}
```

And in your subclass:

```
public class ComparableCircle2D extends GeometricObject2D<ComparableCircle2D> {

    @Override 
    public boolean contains(ComparableCircle2D circle){
      //  return....;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what generics are exactly for, do the following:

```
abstract class GeometricObject2D<T extends GeometricObject2D> {
  public abstract boolean contains(T g);
}

class ComparableCircle2D extends GeometricObject2D<ComparableCircle2D> {
  public boolean contains(ComparableCircle2D circle){
        return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: your solution is the same as gabriele's, but i can't choose two answers, otherwise i would've done it :/ thank you so much, though!

Answer (score 1):

your class must implement/override all methods of the abstract class and interface otherwise you'll have to mark it as `abstract`.

```
public boolean contains(ComparableCircle2D circle){
```

this is not a valid override as the `contains()` method in `GeometricObject2D` takes `GeometricObject2D`

Answer (score 1):

You must have the exact same arguments to override a method. Hence you're extending a substract class, all the abstract methods have to be implemented.

Here is a solution for you

```
public boolean contains(GeometricObject2D circle){
    if (!(circle instanceof ComparableCircle2D)) {
        throw InputMismatchException();
    } else {
    // method
    }
}
```

Or (depending on the logic of your own code)

```
public boolean contains(GeometricObject2D circle){
    if (!(circle instanceof ComparableCircle2D)) {
        return false;
    } else {
    // method
    }
}
```